# Cmap and Clist concepts in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the similar function used for Cmap and Clist in iphone..

Can anyone tell me ?

Is this possible to use Cmap and clist in xcode..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary` (and its mutable variant `NSMutableDictionary`) are `CMap` equivalents.
It seems there's no such thing as `Clist` - only `NSArray` as `CArray` analog...